# How to generate Spring-boot REST API documentation using Swagger2?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to generate REST API documentation of my Spring-boot application using swagger2.

Here are my application.properties file contents:

```
server.port = ${port:8082}
server.contextPath=/myServicePath
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${mysql-host:localhost}:${mysql-port:3306}/${mysql-dbname:mydb}
spring.datasource.username=${mysql-user:root}
spring.datasource.password=${mysql-password:password}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Here is my swaggerConfig.Java:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.ApiSelectorBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger.web.UiConfiguration;
import static springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors.*;
@Configuration
public class ApiDocumentationConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Docket documentation() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
      .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
        //.paths(regex("/.*"))
        .build()
      .pathMapping("/")
      .apiInfo(metadata());
    }
    @Bean
    public UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
      return UiConfiguration.DEFAULT;
    }
    private ApiInfo metadata() {
      return new ApiInfoBuilder()
    .title("My awesome API")
    .description("Some description")
    .version("1.0")
    .contact("my-email@domain.org")
    .build();
    }
}
```

Here is Application.Java:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@EnableSwagger2
public class Application {
    public static void main( String[] args ) 
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
@Path("/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@RestController

public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @ApiOperation(value = "doStuff", nickname = "doStuff", response = Response.class)
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public String doStuff(@RequestBody String command) {
        return "TestString";
    }       
}
```

I am using Spring-boot 1.4.0 and swagger2. I have added below dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>            
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

When I use url http://localhost:8082/swagger-ui.html,
I got error 404.

Can anybody help me to figure this out?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `@Path`?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin I have defined contextPath in application.properties.

Comment: `@Path` is from JAX-RS. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with that annotation. By the way, you also have `@Produces` and `@Consumes` from JAX-RS.

Comment: Not related directly but upgrading to version 2.6.0 of Springfox will be a much better experience in terms of bugs. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might need a resource handler. Could be something like:

```java
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}
```

Comment: Where should I add this snippet?

Comment: @Vishwas Create a class that extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and annotate it with `@EnableWebMvc`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. let me try out this.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin you shouldn't have to do this in springboot. Autoconfiguration will take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

I consider you have to use @EnableSwagger2 with your @Configuration annotated class prior to @SpingBootApplication annotated. Take a look on this [article](http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api) closer

Try add .paths(PathSelectors.any()) :

```
    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
          .build();                                           
    }
```